# What are the Python thread + Unix signals semantics?

Tags: python, unix, multithreading, posix, signals

What are the rules surrounding Python threads and how Unix signals are handled?

Is `KeyboardInterrupt`, which is triggered by `SIGINT` but handled internally by the Python runtime, handled differently?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, when setting up signal handlers using the [`signal`](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html) module, you must create them in the main thread.  You will receive an exception if you try to create them in a separate thread.

Signal handlers registered via the `signal.signal()` function will always be called in the main thread.  On architectures which support sending signals to threads, at the C level I believe the Python runtime ignores all signals on threads and has a signal handler on the main thread, which it uses to dispatch to your Python-code signal handler.

The documentation for the `thread` module states that the [`KeyboardInterrupt`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt) exception (which is ordinarily triggered by `SIGINT`) can be [delivered to an arbitrary thread](http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html) unless you have the `signal` module available to you, which all Unix systems should have.  In that case, it's delivered to the main thread.  If you're on a system without `signal`, you'll have to catch `KeyboardInterrupt` in your thread and call [`thread.interrupt_main()`](http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html#thread.interrupt_main) to re-raise it in the main thread.

More information can be found in the Python docs for the [`thread`](http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html) and [`signal`](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html) modules.

Comment: Interesting, I thought only the main thread would receive `KeyboardInterrupt`s.

Comment: Yeah!  Who knows why it isn't.

Comment: In my experience, and by my reading of the documentation, when the `signal` module is available, `KeyboardInterrupt` is only delivered to the main thread.

Comment: Miles: Yeah, I think you and Bastien are right.  A quick check of some python-list posts and a peek at the code back this up.  I've corrected the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

From the [`signal`](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html) documentation:

> Some care must be taken if both signals and threads are used in the same program. The fundamental thing to remember in using signals and threads simultaneously is: always perform `signal()` operations in the main thread of execution. Any thread can perform an `alarm()`, `getsignal()`, `pause()`, `setitimer()` or `getitimer()`; only the main thread can set a new signal handler, and the main thread will be the only one to receive signals (this is enforced by the Python signal module, even if the underlying thread implementation supports sending signals to individual threads). This means that signals can’t be used as a means of inter-thread communication. Use locks instead.